# Raspberry Pi doesn't recognize HDD in powered USB Hub

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, hard-drive, connection, usb-hub

I just bought an powered *USB hub* (http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-4761_UH700.html) so that I can connect an external NTFS HDD ( http://tw.adata.com/es/hdd/feature/168) to my **raspberry pi 2 Model B** with **raspbian** (The hub is because the Raspberry pi cannot supply enough current to the HDD) When I do:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

I am not capable to see the hard drive, and when I do

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

and then I connect my USB hub I get:

```
Jun  9 19:42:10 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1511.283915] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32                                                                                                    
Jun  9 19:42:11 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1511.474007] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32                                                                                                                        
Jun  9 19:42:11 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1511.663918] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg                                                                                                                       
Jun  9 19:42:11 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1512.083923] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 10, error -32                                                                                                                     
Jun  9 19:42:11 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1512.163925] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg                                                                                                                      
Jun  9 19:42:12 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1512.583906] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 11, error -32                                                                                                                     
Jun  9 19:42:12 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1512.584106] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I have already tried:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo rpi-update
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

and still nothing. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I just did:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

and add to the end:

```
max usb current=1
```

and reboot

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```